# regex replace adding unwanted additional bracket

Tags: java, regex

Okay, so here's my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class View {

    private String item;
    private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}");
    Matcher m;
    Map map;

    public View(String str){
        this.item = str;
        m = p.matcher(item);
        map = new HashMap();

        while(m.find()){
            String key = m.group(1);
            map.put(key, null);
        }
    }

    public void add(String str, Object obj){
        for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();){
            Map.Entry<String, Object> e = it.next();
            String key = e.getKey();
            Object value = e.getValue();

            if(str.equals(key)){
                e.setValue(obj);
            }
        }
    }

    public Object render(){
        for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();){
            Map.Entry<String, Object> e = it.next();
            String key = e.getKey();
            Object value = e.getValue();

            System.out.println(key + "" + value);

         item = item.replaceAll("\\{" + key + "\\}", value.toString());

        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

and I need it to pass these two tests:

```
@Test
    public void testList() {
        View view = new View("<table>{rows}</table>");
        view.add("rows", Arrays.asList("<tr><td>Louis</td><td>Armstrong</td></tr>", "<tr><td>Benny</td><td>Goodman</td></tr>"));
        Assert.assertEquals("<table><tr><td>Louis</td><td>Armstrong</td></tr><tr><td>Benny</td><td>Goodman</td></tr></table>", view.render());
    }

    @Test
    public void testView() {
        View view = new View("<table>{rows}</table>");

        View row1 = new View("<tr><td>{firstName}</td><td>{lastName}</td></tr>");
        row1.add("firstName", "Louis");
        row1.add("lastName", "Armstrong");
        View row2 = new View("<tr><td>{firstName}</td><td>{lastName}</td></tr>");
        row2.add("firstName", "Benny");
        row2.add("lastName", "Goodman");

        view.add("rows", Arrays.asList(row1, row2));
        Assert.assertEquals("<table><tr><td>Louis</td><td>Armstrong</td></tr><tr><td>Benny</td><td>Goodman</td></tr></table>", view.render());
    }
```

However, I keep getting errors when I run the tests and I'm not sure how to go about fixing the issue.

I've noticed that what is going on is that instead of simply putting one bracket [ around the item to replace the string with, it is putting two.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<<table>[<tr><td>Louis</td><td>Armstrong</td></tr><tr><td>Benny</td><td>Goodman</td></tr>]</table>> but was:<<table>[[<tr><td>Louis</td><td>Armstrong</td></tr>, <tr><td>Benny</td><td>Goodman</td></tr>]]</table>>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
```

If you look, it says it expects `[<tr><td>Louis...` but is instead getting `[[<tr><td>Louis...`

Im not sure how to fix this issue, so if someone would please point me in the right direction.

Comment: You're using the wrong tool for this job. You should investigate XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `String` representation of the `List` you pass in the tests is not what you expect it to be.

If you run this code

```
List list = Arrays.asList("<p>foo</p>", "<p>bar</p>");
System.out.println(list.toString());
```

it will output to the console

```
[<p>foo</p>, <p>bar</p>]
```

In your test, you expect it to output HTML without any further markup, like so

```
<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>
```

To solve this issue, you'll have to iterate over the object you pass if applicable. The easiest method is to change the signature of the `add` method so that you can always iterate over the object

```
void add(String str, Iterable obj);
```

If that is not an option because you will also pass non-iterables (e.g. plain `String` objects), you can overload your method. Alternatively, you can do some custom type checking at runtime but that can get ugly fast.

EDIT:

you can just add (not replace) a method with the signature I provided before. For the second test, you need to implement the `toString()` method. Code like so:

```
public void add(String str, Iterable obj){
    for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();){
        Map.Entry<String, Object> e = it.next();
        String key = e.getKey();

        if(str.equals(key)){
            String val = "";
            for (Object o : obj)
            {
                val += o.toString();
            }
            e.setValue(val);
        }
    }
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return render().toString();
}
```

Comment: I tried to do as you mentioned and implement iterable, however I cannot change the signature of the add method, so I tried it another way which failed. Do you have any other ideas?